# Make Padding To UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, xcode6

I want to make padding for my UIView ,how to do that ?

I have tried like,

```
      self.ProductCodeView.bounds = CGRectInset(self.ProductCodeView.frame, 5.0f, 5.0f);
```

but , i reduced the size of the view only , please help me to do that .

Comment: see if outlets are properly attached and try to give 10.0 f

Comment: Ok , but that is also reduce the size of the uiview. I want to move little bit of my uiview to left or right through coding in objective c

Comment: Then try to update frames

Comment: how to update the frames through coding ,because that uiview is created through storyboard not in coding , i want to move little bit sometimes not in all the cases , so please tell how to do padding for uiview through coding which is created in storyboard .